# MD5 Hashing for Android

Tags: java, android, hash

Ok all here is my problem. I am attempting to encrypt a string with the MD5 hash. Here is the string I am attempting to hash: `NjljNWZjZWJhYTY1YjU2MGVhZjA2YzNmYmViNDgxYWU0NGI4ZDYxOA==`

Here is the expected output: `aaf53a928ca9baa6df03a5fe6e3c7b71`

And here is what I am getting in my Android application: `3cc9a8b9d101349af1b4e17ae3b7450f`

Now here is my code I am using to do this:

```
public final String computeMD5Hash(final String pass){
    try {
        // Create MD5 Hash
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        digest.update(pass.getBytes());
        byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

        // Create Hex String
        StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {
            String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);
            while (h.length() < 2)
                h = "0" + h;
            hexString.append(h);
        }
        System.out.println(hexString.toString());
        return hexString.toString();

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "";
```

With this code running on Android I get the unexpected result above, but when I run this code just as a java program passing in the same string I get the expected output...

What on earth is going on? I have been stumped on this for days and scoured the Internet for a clue. I have tried changing the bytes to and from UTF-8, ASCII, ISO-8859-1, and using the default. Always getting the same string that is incorrect.

**-----------Edit----------Solution------**

I figured it out, I was using Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.Default) what I should have been using the Base63.NO_WRAP flag option... a newline was being entered and throwing everything off. Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

It appears you must be passing in the wrong string.  I just ran your code myself and the output was: aaf53a928ca9baa6df03a5fe6e3c7b71

I directly set the string passed in to the one you provided.

Test it out for yourself.  Remove the final String and explicitly set the value of pass to NjljNWZjZWJhYTY1YjU2MGVhZjA2YzNmYmViNDgxYWU0NGI4ZDYxOA==

Comment: Same here. Check your input :)

Comment: Yup! You are absolutely correct, when I hard code it in the Android app I get the expected output. Just gotta figure out why it isn't being passed correctly. Thanks so much, cant believe I didnt think about actually hard coding it into the Android app <face-palm>